# How to setup SysLogHandler with Django 1.3

Tags: django, syslog

I'm having no luck finding any information on setting up syslog logging with Django 1.3 dictionary configuration.  The Django documents don't cover syslog and the python documentation is less than clear and doesn’t cover dictionary config at all.  I've started with the following but I'm stuck on how to configure the SysLogHandler.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'syslog':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['syslog'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'INFO',
        },
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['syslog'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

```
from logging.handlers import SysLogHandler 
... 
        'syslog':{ 
            'level':'DEBUG', 
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler', 
            'formatter': 'verbose', 
            'facility': SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL2, 
        },
...
```

**Warning to future generations:** you pretty much have to do it exactly like the above, weird errors happen if you specify the class directly etc.